# equivalent enumerable.max function in delphi

Tags: delphi

does Delphi have any equivalent of the
csharp code `alphabet.max` where alphabet is a
string variable or is there an equivalent function?

I am trying to port the following code from csharp
to delphi.

```
string alphabet = "ABCD";
invalphabet = new int[alphabet.Max() + 1];
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.90).aspx

thanks

Comment: And what would alphabet.max() return? The value of the last element in alphabet? The amount of items in alphabet? The hightest value in alphabet?

Comment: @ObliviousSage No it would not. It would return the highest `Char` value, where `Char` is a 16 bit UTF-16 character type

Comment: I corrected the code. It's `Max()` rather than `max()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
uses
  Math; // for the Max function
....
var
  i: Integer;
  invalphabet: array of Integer;
  maxOrdinal: Integer;
....
maxOrdinal := -1;
for i := 1 to Length(alphabet) do
  maxOrdinal := Max(maxOrdinal, ord(alphabet[i]));
if maxOrdinal = -1 then
  // handle error condition
SetLength(invalphabet, maxOrdinal + 1);
```

Be alive to possible encoding mismatches. The C# code uses UTF-16, and the Delphi code uses either UTF-16 or ANSI depending on your Delphi version. Of course, you may supply an `alphabet` that is restricted to ASCII.